# How to grant access to a user to all content created by certain users?

Tags: users

I've been looking all the options commented on [Controlling Acces to Content Overview](https://www.drupal.org/node/270000) but I don't see any that allow one particular user to access all content created by other particular users.

Something like: **User A have permissions to see all nodes created by users B, C and D**.
(No need to include a reference or a taxonomy term to each node).

Any insights?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry telling you that as far as I know there is nothing like this out of box.
Maybe if you mention the requirement we will be able to help you.
For now don't think about users and think about roles. if you want to make it more flexible I suggest using workbench access so the created content will have a section (Taxonomy term) and the section will be accesed by user A and B only.
Hope that help

Comment: Thanks for your answer! About what you say about thinking about roles, not users, it is possible to grant access to one role to all the nodes another rol can access? Rol A has access to all nodes created by users with rol B?
What I'd like is that one specific user can see what a group of users do, another specific user can see what another group of users do and so on.